# Azure Get User Delegation Failing on Expiry Format

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-sas

I'm trying to get a [user delegation SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas) for Azure Storage, using the REST API.

I've got an account, which has the required roles for the storage account, and the account has authenticated successfully and returned a Bearer token from the login endpoint.

When I request the user delegation key, I keep getting the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidXmlNodeValue</Code>
    <Message>The value for one of the XML nodes is not in the correct format.
RequestId:9b7a22e3-601e-0082-7bee-060981000000
Time:2021-02-19T18:38:48.1286734Z</Message>
    <XmlNodeName>Expiry</XmlNodeName>
    <XmlNodeValue>2021-02-19T19:30:00</XmlNodeValue>
</Error>
```

The body I'm submitting is copied from [the Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-user-delegation-key), :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<KeyInfo>  
    <Start>2021-02-19T18:30:00</Start>
    <Expiry>2021-02-19T19:30:00</Expiry>
</KeyInfo>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or missing for this to be failing?

The roles assigned on Azure are:

[image: Azure user roles]

And the request headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer ...
x-ms-version: 2020-04-08
Content-Type: text/xml
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.10
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: df276a57-747c-45dd-a849-15ac6ad7b45b
Host: ....blob.core.windows.net
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 147
```

Comment: Could you try format the expiry time like this: `2021-02-19T19:30:00Z`. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/formatting-datetime-values

Comment: I modify my answer, would mind accept it for others to refer?

Comment: Done, thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be your token **life time is too short to get it effective**.  My suggestion is, set the expiry time more than **8 hours** longer than start time.

> The value of the expiry time may be a maximum of seven days from the
> start time.

Format your expiry time like this:

```
2021-02-19T19:30:00Z
```

Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/formatting-datetime-values

Comment: Not the problem unfortunately - I've tried expiries after 12hrs, 24hrs, 48hs, they all fail with the same message.

Comment: Yes, this format worked for me: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ` I originally had fractional seconds but this didn't work, which is confusing as the docs state that they are supported...